# How to Use Material Design in Android App?

Tags: android, android-studio, material-design

I've gone to the Android Developer documentation to see how I can use material design, here:

> https://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html

and here:

> https://developer.android.com/training/material/get-started.html

Essentially, I would like for someone to summarize how to set up/use material design, because I feel like there is a lot of information on the developer docs, and I can't seem to wrap my mind around it.
If you'd rather give me a link to a guide created by someone else, that'd be helpful as well.

I'm also using API level 19 (target SDK version 19) and from what I can see, I'll need to use `com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.+`

I'm also using Android Studio, and not eclipse.

EDIT: I would like to be able to use material design for devices that are not running Android 5.0 Lollipop, because according to the Android distribution data, there are less than 0.1% of devices running Lollipop: [Android Distribution Data](http://puu.sh/ekOk3/10adc41d9b.png)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Install SDK platform of `Android 5.0 SDK` then update your Support Library and Support Repository to the latest version via the SDK-Manager.

Take a look at this link for creating material app

http://developer.android.com/training/material/index.html

With support libraries, you can provide similar behaviour on older devices like:

- Using the Material Theme
- Subset of UI widgets like

  - `EditText`
  - `Spinner`
  - `RadioButton`

Also take a look at [android design support library](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html).

More information :

- https://chris.banes.me/2014/10/17/appcompat-v21/
- http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html
- https://developer.android.com/training/material/compatibility.html

But for using some concepts like `FloatingActionButton` in your application you can use this library :
https://github.com/makovkastar/FloatingActionButton

More libraries available here

https://android-arsenal.com/

Comment: Yes. I've looked through all of that. I've also edited my original post. I want to use material design for devices not running Android 5.0, but the developer docs are not entirely _clear_ on how to do that. I see what it says, and I've read it, but I feel like everything is mashed together.

Comment: Great. Thank you for the guides. I'll look into them and hopefully everything works out well.

Answer (score 5):

Use following style with appcompat_v7 support library:

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme" >
    ......
</application>
```

styles.xml

```
<style name="MyMaterialTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Here is my demo project for Material Design below 5.0 with Toolbar and Recycler view:
[MaterialDesign_Part1](https://github.com/rahulparihar09/MaterialDesign_Part1)