# Are there "helpers" in Codename One to write Material Design apps as in Android

Tags: mobile, material-design, codenameone

I have designed and released a mobile app for Android and iOS which is often depicted by the users as poorly designed. Indeed the app only features buttons scattered around the main Form that each opens a different form to show pieces of information or do an action. The app uses CN1 flat blue theme along with material icons but it does not look enough to make it material designed.

Thus I am planning to redesign the app and make it a material design one. While reading the [material design specifications](https://material.google.com/) the tasks appears huge because there are many parameters to take into account to stick to the specifications although there is no obligation to apply them all.

However according to [Android developers site](https://developer.android.com/design/material/index.html) and this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27869167/how-to-use-material-design-in-android-app) it seems that Android (version 5.0 onwards) provides helpers (eg a material design theme) to help follow the material design specifications. Are there such helpers in Codename One, or do I have to do it manualy (ie creating shadows, animations linked to actions, component styles, typo, dialogs ...) ? Or put another way, is there a way to give CN1 some hints about the app (primary color is xyz, this piece of information is a subheading, ...) and let CN1 apply the material design rules (animations between forms, shadows, ...) ?

Hope my question makes sense and can receive some help different (if possible) from what is provided in [this SO question about Codename One support of Material Design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35025849/google-material-design-in-codenameone) as my app is already using material icons and native typos.

Thanks in advance for the help provided,

Cheers,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you check out apps such as [JAT](https://www.codenameone.com/featured-jat.html) or [buua](https://www.codenameone.com/featured-buua.html) you will notice they apply the material design principals very well.

The `Toolbar` class should already comply with most material design principals by default and the `FontImage` class includes the standard material design icons.

We have task specific classes such as [BubbleTransition](http://www.codenameone.com/blog/shape-clipping-bubble-transition.html) to implement effects such as the floating button turning into a dialog etc.

What I find most important in material design and design in general is:

1. Typography - use a proper native: font that matches the occasion and looks good on the device.
2. Spacing - use spacing intelligently and use millimeters to keep it consistent between devices.
3. Colors - pick a palette and stick to it consistently, material design has some great color palettes that really make the app shine.
4. Simplicity - don't try to much. Simple is gorgeous. Yes you can add more shadows, animations etc. but you don't really need those and very few users would really notice that work. Everyone will notice if the app is minimalistic (in a good way).

Screenshots of the app might not be good form on stackoverflow but if you post screenshots/link to your app in the discussion forum I'd be happy to give you specific tips. Notice that hiring a designer to do some work or using a design template would be very helpful too.

Comment: Thanks Shai, I really appreciate your material design summary! I'll post svreenshots on CN1 discussion forum? And sure hiring a pro would yield awesome design but it's also good to learn the basics by myself!

Comment: I think that one of the best ways to learn is thru observation of a professional doing his job. Check out the developer guide themeing section where we discuss the conversion of a  PSD design to an app.